# output is not printing string in python

Tags: python

i have made a program but the output that i'm getting is

```
(<q3v3.Student instance at 0x023BB620>, 'is doing the following modules:', ' <q3v3.Module instance at 0x023BB670> <q3v3.Module instance at 0x023BB698>')
```

For example , the above output should give me Alice is doing following module : biology, chemistry

Help

this is my full code:

```
class Student : 
    def __init__(self,students): 
        self.students= students 
        print self.students

   #def __str__(self):  # when i used this i've got error type TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
    #print str(self.students)


class Module:
    def __init__(self,modules):
        self.modules = modules
        print self.modules

    #def __str__(self):
        #print str(self.modules)


class Registrations (Student,Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list= []
        self.stulist = []
        self.modulist= []

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.list)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.list)


    def add(self,students,modules):
        self.list.append((students,modules))
        #print (self.list)



    def students(self,modules):
        for i in self.list:
            if i[1] == modules:
                self.modulist.append((i[0]))
        return iter(self.modulist)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.students)


    def modules(self,students):
        for i in self.list:
            if i[0] == students:
                self.stulist.append((i[1]))
        return iter(self.stulist)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.modules)
```

## i need to import my program to be able to run it to this :

```
from q3v4 import *


james = Student('james')
alice = Student('alice')
mary = Student('mary')

agm = Module('agm')
ipp = Module('ipp')

r = Registrations()
r.add(james,agm)
r.add(alice,agm)
r.add(alice,ipp)


mstr = ''
for m in map(str,r.modules(alice)):
    mstr = mstr+' '+m
print(alice, 'is doing the following modules:', mstr)
sstr = ''
for s in map(str,r.students(agm)):
   sstr = sstr+' '+s
print(agm, 'has the following students:', sstr)

print(r)
```

Comment: Have you defined `__str__` methods for your `Student` and `Module` 
classes?

Comment: you question is terribly unclaer :)

Comment: yes i have defined __str__ methods for those two classes. Really sorry for not making it clear. I will post my code soon

Comment: sorry my codes are misalliged again.

Comment: i just realized that there was a typing error for the def __str__. Now that i corrected it, i'm getting error instead that goes TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `__str__` method in your `Student` class, and do something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name # Here the string you want to print
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 2? If so, `print` is a keyword, not a function. There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Write `print foo, bar` instead of `print(foo, bar)`.

   The difference is that `print(foo, bar)` is actually printing out the *tuple* `(foo, bar)`, which uses the `repr()` representation of each element, rather than its `str()`.
2. At the very top of your file, write `from __future__ import print_function`. This will magically convert `print` from a keyword into a function, causing your code to work as expected.

If you *are* using Python 3, my answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @user3072782: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: im using python version 2.7.1

Comment: @user3072782: Then follow my first suggestion.